# How to bind one utterance with two or more intent in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I have two intent
1: Weather Intent
2: NewsIntent
If user is asked at time in the app.. Would you like to know the weather of Boston, user will response Yes or No.
If user is asked at any time in the app... Would you like to know the sports news, user will response Yes or No.
How would i bind Yes or No with these two intent and how would I handle this in the code? How would I know that this Yes is for which intent?

And if there is way to do that then if user is saying yes, i would like to pass few value to the intent as well. like if user says yes to weather then i would like to know the city, in this case Boston.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible by using followup. Check out the documentation and examples here: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.followup